# CodeInjection using CreateRemoteThread and WriteProcessMemory

Tags: delphi, winapi

On CodeProject ([Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces)) i read about using `CreateRemoteThread` and `WriteProcessMemory` to inject code in another process.

> 1. Retrieve a HANDLE to the remote process (OpenProces).
> 2. Allocate memory in the remote process's address space for injected data (VirtualAllocEx).
> 3. Write a copy of the initialised INJDATA structure to the allocated memory (WriteProcessMemory).
> 4. Allocate memory in the remote process's address space for injected code.
> 5. Write a copy of ThreadFunc to the allocated memory.
> 6. Start the remote copy of ThreadFunc via CreateRemoteThread.
> 7. Wait until the remote thread terminates (WaitForSingleObject).
> 8. Retrieve the result from the remote process (ReadProcessMemory or GetExitCodeThread).
> 9. Free the memory allocated in Steps #2 and #4 (VirtualFreeEx).
>      Blockquote
> 10. Close the handles retrieved in Steps #6 and #1 (CloseHandle).

As INJDATA is a structure i assume any kind of parameter / variable / record will work.

It is written very good but however I struggle converting this to Delphi.

So i want to inject my procedure `GetNumber` in notepad.exe that displays a number i can declare in a record.

```
type
  TInjectData = record
    FNumber: Integer;
  end; 


procedure GetNumber(var pData: TInjectData);
begin
  MessageBoxA(0, PChar(IntToStr(pData.FNumber)), '', 0);
end;
```

I wrote a function `InjectCode` that should do the job.

```
  procedure InjectCode;
var
  hWindow: THandle;
  dwProcId: Cardinal;
  hProcess: THandle;
  hThread: THandle;
  myData: TInjectData;
  pDataRemote, pCodeRemote: Pointer;
  dwBytesWritten: DWORD;
  cbCodeSize: Integer;
  dwThreadId: DWORD;

begin
  myData.FNumber := 42;

  hWindow := FindWindow('Notepad', nil);
  ShowMessage(Format('hWindow: %d', [hWindow]));

  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow, dwProcId);
  ShowMessage(Format('dwProcId: %d', [dwProcId]));

  // 1. Retrieve a HANDLE to the remote process (OpenProces)
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or
    PROCESS_VM_OPERATION or PROCESS_VM_WRITE, False, dwProcId);

  ShowMessage(Format('hProcess: %d', [hProcess]));


  // 2. Allocate memory in the remote process's address space for injected data (VirtualAllocEx)
  // pDataRemote = the address (in the remote process) where myData will be copied to
  pDataRemote := VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nil, SizeOf(myData), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  ShowMessage(Format('pDataRemote: %d', [Integer(pDataRemote)]));


  // 3. Write a copy of the initialised INJDATA structure to the allocated memory (WriteProcessMemory)
  WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pDataRemote, @myData, SizeOf(myData), dwBytesWritten);
  ShowMessage(Format('dwBytesWritten pDataRemote: %d', [dwBytesWritten]));


  // Calculate the number of bytes that ThreadFunc occupies
  // cbCodeSize = LPBYTE(AfterGetNumber) - LPBYTE(GetNumber);
  cbCodeSize := 2500; // correct calculation not yet implemented


  // 4. Allocate memory in the remote process's address space for injected code
  pCodeRemote := VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nil, cbCodeSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  ShowMessage(Format('pCodeRemote: %d', [Integer(pCodeRemote)]));


  // 5. Write a copy of GetNumber to the allocated memory
  WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pCodeRemote, @GetNumber, cbCodeSize, dwBytesWritten);
  ShowMessage(Format('dwBytesWritten pCodeRemote: %d', [dwBytesWritten]));


  // 6. Start the remote copy of GetNumber via CreateRemoteThread
  hThread := CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, nil, 0, pCodeRemote, pDataRemote, 0, dwThreadId);
  ShowMessage(Format('hThread: %d', [hThread]));
  ShowMessage(Format('dwThreadId: %d', [dwThreadId]));



  // 7. Wait until the remote thread terminates (WaitForSingleObject)
  WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);


  // 8. Retrieve the result from the remote process (ReadProcessMemory or GetExitCodeThread).
  // not needed in this example


  // 9. Free the memory allocated in Steps #2 and #4 (VirtualFreeEx)
  if Assigned(pDataRemote) then
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pDataRemote, 0, MEM_RELEASE );

  if Assigned(pCodeRemote) then
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pCodeRemote, 0, MEM_RELEASE );


  // 10. Close the handles retrieved in Steps #6 and #1 (CloseHandle).
  if hProcess <> 0 then
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

  if hThread <> 0 then
    CloseHandle(hThread);
end;
```

But whenever i call the procedure no MessageBox appears.
I have no experience with code injection so please bear with me as i already spent some days trying to figure this out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should start by checking if any API call fails, and check the error code.

Comment: The total absence of error checking is a problem. You've made the classic beginner's mistake of writing the entire program, running it, and then not knowing where to look when it fails. Break it down in to small pieces. Add error checking. Debug.

Comment: @ElderBug good point.

After some debugging i figured out that  hThread  (CreateRemoteThread) is still 0 after the function call.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I added my checks and edited the post.

Comment: We can't see any of the diagnostics. However, as my answer explains this approach cannot work.

Answer (score 3):

You've not performed any error checking. So you don't know how the code fails. You need to get into the habit of checking for errors.

You should also be aware that calling convention is important when injecting a remote thread. You must supply a thread function with this signature:

```
function ThreadFunc(Data: Pointer): Cardinal; stdcall;
```

Another problem is that the target process is Notepad, surely a 64 bit process. You can't inject into. 64 bit process from a 32 bit process. And certainly not with 32 bit code!

However, once you fix all the bugs your code can still never work. That's because the function you inject relies on the Delphi RTL being present. It links to a Windows API function. It calls `IntToStr`. It performs a `PChar()` cast. All of these things require the Delphi RTL. What's more they require the RTL to reside at the address it does in the injector because it is statically linked.

To inject code in this way, the code must stand alone. If you want to learn about injection you should start by injecting a DLL which is much easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  

I successfully injected an DLL like described in the [CodeProject post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces#section_2)

I changed the GetNumber procedure so it doesn't rely on the Delphi RTL. However the assigned value hThread is still 0.  

Can you elaborate "the code must stand alone", please?

Comment: It has to stand alone because there's no RTL in the target process. You are going to find it next to impossible to live without the RTL. Did you read the docs for CreateRemoteThread? What does it tell you to do when 0 is returned?

Comment: I spent quite some time on the msdn site of CreateRemoteThread. I also called GetLastError but it also returns 0.

Comment: That's surprising that CreateRemoteThread would fail and GetLastError return 0. It's not much fun discussing code we can't see.

Comment: What is the target process? Oh I see, it's 64 bit notepad.

Comment: I just made a sample output using a memo instead of ShowMessage and somehow GetLastError() returns 5 (=Access Denied). I guess ShowMessage overrides it? I am targeting notepad.

Comment: I explained in the answer that you can't create a remote thread in a 64 bit target with a 32 bit injector. Fundamentally though you are going to have to accept that you can't expect to inject code in the way you are attempting. You aren't going to be able to live without the RTL. I've identified many problems with the code in the question. Please don't expect me to get in to an extended debugging session. That's back to you.

Comment: Thanks for bringing the inside David! Of course i don't expect you to debugging my code. I'm glad to learn this lot today! So this is very limited to nearly calling no functions at all. Would it be possible to call a function from user32.dll like FindWindow in the injected function without using Delphi RTL?

Comment: You've got a chicken and egg situation there. How can you link to a function in an external DLL without an RTL? How can you call LoadLibrary, GetModuleHandle, GetProcAddress? Where can you find the addresses of those functions? I don't think it's very easy. Without wishing to seem disrespectful, I think that is beyond your current scope of expertise.

Comment: That's what i thought. I think i'll have to pass on injecting code this way with Delphi. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The target process doesn't need to have the same kernel32.MessageBoxA address, probably it's that. I would get the address in notepad.exe before using it.